# Monitor web server usage on Linux Debian PER DOMAIN

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, debian-lenny, virtualhost

I have been using munin and monit to monitor the overall details of my web server, but as it hosts multiple sites, I would like to know how to monitor per-domain hosted, or something similar.

The main statistics I'd like to see are bandwidth, RAM and disk usage, per domain/vhost.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need several tools to measure this.

- For bandwidth, any modern web stats monitor like awstats or webalizer will give you a detailed account per domain, that won't be live but as close as you need to be, don't base those measures on Google Analytics since it's not an accurate representation of your total used bandwidth. You can also divide your site and give an IP to each host, it's a big bloated but also a good way.
- For RAM there's no good way to check really, unless you get into some dark arts or prepend php code to measure, you're pretty much on your own on this one
- As per disk usage, establishing a quota system on your partition will give you exact usage per user (of course this assumes that you have one user per web hosting account). Also having a small script running `du` should do the job